# Firebase Admin SDK - How lacking is the Java release compared to the Node.JS?

Tags: maven, firebase, push-notification, firebase-admin

I am looking to create a microservice in the backend of my android and iOS app that sends push notification requests to firebase (using maven to organize project). I would like to use the Java admin SDK for this as I am looking to make this call in the backend in this app server rather than right from the android or iOS side. I have been exploring this API and the Java version is missing two APIs that the Node.JS one currently has. I read up on what the two APIs do but I was wondering if anyone who has been working with the admin SDK know how the two Java APIs missing will handicap me in terms of features?

Comment: There is currently not 100% feature parity between the JavaScript and Java admin SDKs for Firebase.  Everything you see in the documentation should be accurate.  You might want to look into using Cloud Functions for Firebase to power the backend for you app, even if you prefer Java over JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you won't find the following 2 APIs in the Java Admin SDK:

- Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)
- User management

User management API for Java is currently [being developed](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/33). FCM will be added in the near future too.